# Symfony2 Разобрать CSV и записать в базу

Tags: php, symfony2

Пытаюсь распарсить csv

и чото затык

```
try {
        $handle = fopen($test, "r");
        while (fgetcsv($handle) !== false) {
            $data = fgetcsv($handle);
            if ($data !== false) {
                $output->writeln(sprintf('Updating table price_selected_hotel...'));
                $selectedHotels = new PriceSelectedHotels;
                foreach ($data as $row) {
                    $output->writeln($row);
                    $selectedHotels->setCityCode($row['']);
                    $selectedHotels->setCheckInDate($row['']);
                    $selectedHotels->setSelectedHotels($row['']);
                    $selectedHotels->setInsertTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

                    $em->flush();
                    $em->clear();
                }
                $output->writeln(sprintf('Updating success'));
            }
        }
        return 0;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $output->writeln($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
        return 1;
    }
```

файл выглядет вот так

> check_in_date;city;selected
>
> ---
>
> 2016-04-01;LD6J;CA11SM, CAN861, UK02W7, UK0NGW
>
> ---
>
> 2016-04-02;LD6J;UK0G54, CAN861, UK0PA1

сепаратор ; столбец selected это массив

Comment: А затык как выглядит? Что не так? Не разбирается, разбирается не так, как ожидалось или трудности с помещением в базу данных?

Comment: 1 не могу вникнуть как достать строчку и нормально её распарсить
` $selectedHotels->setCityCode($row['']);`
                    `$selectedHotels->setCheckInDate($row['']);`
                    `$selectedHotels->setSelectedHotels($row['']);`
т.е. что писать в `$row[' ** СЮДА ** ']`

Answer (score 1):

Если я не забыл как разбираются `csv`, то попробуйте так:

```
 try {
        $handle = fopen($test, "r");
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== false) {
                $output->writeln(sprintf('Updating table price_selected_hotel...'));
                $selectedHotels = new PriceSelectedHotels;

                $output->writeln($row);

                list($date, $city, $hotels) = $row;
                $selectedHotels->setCityCode($city);
                $selectedHotels->setCheckInDate($date);
                $selectedHotels->setSelectedHotels( explode(',', $hotels) );
                $selectedHotels->setInsertTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

                $em->flush();
                $em->clear();
                $output->writeln(sprintf('Updating success'));
        }
        return 0;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $output->writeln($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
        return 1;
    }
```

Вот в этом месте `$selectedHotels->setSelectedHotels( imlode(',', $hotels) );` собирается массив из ваших отелей. Если ваша функция должна принимать строку а не массив, то `explode` не нужен.

**Offtop**
Я могу ошибаться, но я в блоке `try` не вижу ничего, что могло бы вернуть `Exception`, другими словами ваш `try catch` тут бесполезен. Поправьте если ошибаюсь.

Comment: Не найден фаил например =)

Comment: Так, распарсить удалост, но в базу не пишет :с

Comment: @НикитаРассамахин: `fopen` просто вернет `false` в ваш `$handle`. Исключения быть не должно.

Comment: @НикитаРассамахин: Если не пишет в базу, то копайте методы вашего класса `PriceSelectedHotels`. Думаю там что-то не так.

Comment: Не, просто персист забыл)

но вот вопрос, в базу упало вот это 

NULL
NULL
a:1:{i:0;s:0:"";}
2016-03-22

Comment: @НикитаРассамахин: Посмотрите, что лежит в вашем `$row`, например `var_dump($row)` где-то перед листом. Если там есть все данные, то ошибка где-то в методах записи в базу

Comment: list($date, $city, $hotels) = $row; <- тут пусто

Comment: @НикитаРассамахин: Странно, не должно быть такого. А в `$handle` есть ресурс? Или он `false`?

Comment: stream resource {@461
  wrapper_type: "plainfile"
  stream_type: "STDIO"
  mode: "r"
  unread_bytes: 184
  seekable: true
  uri: "/home/rassamakhinny/Downloads/test.csv"
  timed_out: false
  blocked: true
  eof: false
  options: []
}
true
null
null
null

это результат 
dump($handle);
                dump($row);
                dump($date, $city, $hotels)

Comment: @НикитаРассамахин: Это моя ошибка. Пропустил пару скобок в третьей строке. Прошу прощения за свою невнимательность. Обновил ответ.